# How to skin buttons in flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, skins

Just out of curiosity, I am making an effort to optimize every part of our flex app (which is a small part of our app in general). Currently, I am working on optimizing all of the buttons/skins. I have linked a few of the buttons that I use, and some sample code I am using to generate them.

Please advise on how to make this more efficient, usable, and just better overall. Thanks!

[image: First Button, Icon and gray background][image: Second And Third Buttons, different backgrounds but no icons][image: Fourth Button, similar to first, different colors][image: Button with icons but no background]

As you can see, our buttons can be pretty different, but have a similar look and feel. Currently, I am creating 'stateful skins,' by setting up something like this:

```
skin: ClassReference('com.mysite.assets.skins.NavigationButtonSkin');
```

Then, NavigationButtonSkin looks something like this:

```
public class NavigationButtonSkin extends UIComponent {

  // imports, constructor, etc

  protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {

    // initialize fillColors, fillAlphas, roundedCorners, etc

    switch( name ){
      case 'upSkin':
      fillColors = [getStyle('backgroundColor'),getStyle('backgroundColor2')];      
      break;
      // do the same for overSkin, downSkin, disabledSkin, etc
    }

    // use this.graphics to draw background
    // use this.graphics to draw border on top of background

  }

}
```

I commented out some of the straight forward parts, but let me know if this is a bad/inefficient way of doing this - and how to improve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of performances, it would be better that your skin inherits from ProgrammaticSkin instead of UIComponent.
ProgrammticSkin itself inherits from Shape and provides utility methods for skinning such as verticalGradientMatrix, drawRoundRect, ...

That's all I can say looking at your code.

Good point is you use programmatic skin instead of bitmap/swf based skins.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials/books/examples using ProgrammaticSkin? I will google it and have messed with it in the past, but if you have any examples, that would be nice!

Comment: extend from ProgrammaticSkin instead of UIComponent and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not getting where you're getting at with this.  You just want to know if you're doing it right?  I'm assuming that your `skin: ClassReference('com.mysite.assets.skins.NavigationButtonSkin');` is added to the css of a Button, which is good, however I don't see *why* you're doing it all in Actionscript.  Seems inefficient and essentially you're losing all the ability of mxml layouts and support for Catalyst (if you'd ever need it in the future).

Try creating a skin in Flash Builder, it'll create an MXML with the default button skin where you can just edit it as you please.  It's also A LOT easier to do state based design using mxml over actionscript.  You should modify from there on and have a separate skin for each button types.

**EDIT:** oh crap, didn't see this was Flex 3...  Get with the program ;)  Just listen to what Florian said.

Comment: Yeah, we are getting to the point where we are starting to optimize. Anywhere I can get help/speed is something I am considering. We've been through this, I am stuck with Flex 3 (for now) :P When I move forward, stateful mxml skins are something I have read about!

Comment: In terms of development time, ActionScript skins may be inefficient compared to MXML skins because it can be a bit easier to "see" what MXML is drawing when reading the skin code. However, from a performance perspective, ActionScript skins have the advantage. Adobe's mobile components in Flex 4.5 use ActionScript skins instead of MXML because it made a big difference in framerate, especially on things like lists.

Comment: Adobe's Alex Harui even made a blog post recently on this subject, and he suggested using ActionScript skins for any apps that don't perform as well after migrating from Flex 3 to Flex 4: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2011/04/migratory-foul-performance-problems-migrating-from-flex-3-x-to-flex-4-x.html

Of course, it all depends on what one means by efficiency. If MXML skins get the job done, and they perform well, then by all means, use them. If you're using AIR mobile with Flex, or you have a super complex app, it might be smart to consider selectively using ActionScript skins.